# Getting Hibernate to do simple updates, instead of enormous select then updates

Tags: sql, hibernate, query-optimization, sql-update

Lets setup the question first.

What I have is >4 tables: Customer, Address, Order, OrderItems. Each are mapped using Hibernate Annotations and accessed through a Spring DAO/Services layer.

What I am trying to do is merge duplicate customers together. So all that really needs to happen is all orders and addresses associated with customer B, need to update their customer_id foreign key to point to customer A. Then customer B must have its disabled bit set.

Instead of sending these simple queries to our database, hibernate goes crazy and issues a ton of select then update queries. Particularly it selects all order items attached to an order (because this is defined `EAGER`, and this point is not changeable.). To get the selects before update to stop happening I tried adding the hibernate entity annotation on top of the regular `javax.persistence.Entity` like:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true, selectBeforeUpdate = false, dynamicInsert = true)
```

this seemed to have no affect, except with simple queries where it only updated single items in a table.

I get the objects using the following hibernate criteria:

```
            Criteria c1 = null;
            Criteria c2 = null;
            Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Customer.class);
            c.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

            if(resultLimit>0) c.setMaxResults(resultLimit);
            if(timeout>0) c.setTimeout(timeout);
            for(String filter: sqlFilters) {
                if(filter.indexOf("{alias}.customer_")!=-1) c.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(filter));
                else if(filter.indexOf("{alias}.address_")!=-1 && addrsAttached) {
                    if(c1==null)
                        c1 = c.createCriteria("addresses").setFetchMode("type", FetchMode.JOIN);
                    c1.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(filter));
                } else if(filter.indexOf("{alias}.order_")!=-1 && ordersAttached) {
                    if(c2==null)
                        c2 = c.createCriteria("orders").setFetchMode("orderItems", FetchMode.SELECT);
                    c2.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(filter));
                }
            }
            return (List<Customer>) c.list();
```

Then i move all of the address and order objects from customer B to customer A and run a

```
return (Customer) this.getHibernateTemplate().merge(customer);
```

on both customer objects. This ends up creating a ton of select statements that get all of the associated objects (i.e. OrderItems, Products, ProductType, ProductPricingTmpl, etc..)

I need to get these selects removed! If they were not there the query would look normal and be efficient! The Update outputted queries are perfect and dynamic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Checkout this similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161224/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-saving-methods-in-hibernate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue might be in your choice of merge() operation. From the Hibernate javadoc:

> Copy the state of the given object
>   onto the persistent object with the
>   same identifier. If there is no
>   persistent instance currently
>   associated with the session, it will
>   be loaded.

So you're forcing Hibernate to load all of the data in before modifying it.

Try a different operation, such as update() :

> Update the persistent instance with
>   the identifier of the given detached
>   instance.

No promises, though, Hibernate might decide it needs to load it in anyway. The dynamicUpdates=true config might actually make it worse, since it needs to know what's there to start before it can issue dynamic updates.