# SaveOrUpdate Vs Update and Save in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

What is the difference between SaveOrUpdate and Save/Update in NHibernate. Why wouldnt you just always use SaveOrUpdate? Also, what is the point of SaveOrUpdateCopy?

Answer (score 76):

Chapter 9 covers all of this better than I can:

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html

But cliff notes:

`Save()` takes a new object without an identifier and attaches it to the session.  The object will be `INSERT`'d.

`Update()` takes an existing object that has an identifier but is not in the session and attaches it to the session.  The object will be `UPDATE`'d.

`SaveOrUpdate()` looks at the identifier and decides what is necessary in the above.

`SaveOrUpdateCopy()` is special in that say you have two objects with the same identifier -- one in the session and one not.  If you try and `update` the one not in the session an exception is thrown normally (you are now trying to attach two objects that represent the same persistent object to the session).  `SaveOrUpdateCopy()` copies the non-session object state to the session object state.

I'm not sure how you are going to use NH, but for a lot of cases all you need is `Save()`.  The session is doing ALL of the work necessary to know what has to be updated and simply `Flush()` or a `Commit()` does everything you need.

Comment: You usually don't need SaveOrUpdate() because NHibernate tracks changes to every loaded object. To update an object use Session.Get(), make you change then call Session.Flush().

Comment: What is more readable or intention revealing in the code then: `SaveOrUpdate()` or `Flush()` / `Commit()`? Or does it not make a difference (semantic or otherwise)?

Comment: Explicitly flushing your session is probably not necessary. If you commit a transaction or the session goes out of scope/is disposed of the changes will automatically be persisted (or earlier if they need to be for some reason, id generation or the like). Flush is intention-revealing (to me) when you *need* to force the changes automatically, because of read-ioslation or some other esoterica, and just noise otherwise. Anyone familiar with NH will understand the implicit `Update` for attached entities as well, so I tend to the think the same of explicit `SaveOrUpdate` statements as well.

Comment: see this quesion also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161224/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-saving-methods-in-hibernate

Comment: tried to edit but the edit was rejected. Anyways, the behaviour on `Save`is incorrect in the answer. `Save` will either `insert`or `update`as needed. `update`however will throw an exception if trying to save an entity that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @MattEnright you need to `Flush()` if you are not using transaction