# How does NHibernate determine whether to Insert or Update a record?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, s#arp

When using `Session.SaveOrUpdate(myEntity);` how does NHibernate decide how whether to insert a new record or update an existing one?

I am having trouble whilst saving one object in a S#arp project. It is retrieved from storage, then stored in session state for a couple of web requests, then saved back to the database with one property changed (not the S#arp `[DomainSignature]`).

I have, at runtime, compared the object that is about to be persisted with a freshly retrieved version straight from the database using the `Equals()` method and that returns true. However, the object still ends up creating a new row in the database.

Elsewhere in the application this is working fine but I am hoping for a pointer on how NHib is working this out.

Comment: You may want to check this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170962/nhibernate-difference-between-session-merge-and-session-saveorupdate

Comment: Another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150854/saveorupdate-vs-update-and-save-in-nhibernate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `SaveOrUpdate()` is looking for an identifier. If the identifier is present, it will update the record in the database. If the identifier is not present, it will create a new record.

However, it sounds like you might have something funky going on in your session. You might want to try `SaveOrUpdateCopy()` to see if this solves your issue.