# What is the difference between update and insert in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

What makes NHibernate engine determine whether the command is an update or insert?

The command is similar for both update and insert.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SaveOrUpdate Vs Update and Save in NHibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150854/saveorupdate-vs-update-and-save-in-nhibernate)

Answer (score 1):

From official docs: "NHibernate distinguishes "new" (unsaved) instances from "existing" (saved or loaded in a previous session) instances by the value of their identifier (or version, or timestamp) property. The unsaved-value attribute of the  (or , or ) mapping specifies which values should be interpreted as representing a "new" instance. "