# What is the difference between persist() and merge() in JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, entity

What is the difference between persist() and merge() in Hibernate?

`persist()` can create a UPDATE & INSERT query, eg:

```
SessionFactory sef = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sef.openSession();
A a=new A();
session.persist(a);
a.setName("Mario");
session.flush();
```

in this case **query** will be generated like this:

```
Hibernate: insert into A (NAME, ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: update A set NAME=? where ID=?
```

so `persist()` method can **generate** an Insert and an Update.

Now with `merge()`:

```
SessionFactory sef = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sef.openSession();
Singer singer = new Singer();
singer.setName("Luciano Pavarotti");
session.merge(singer);
session.flush();
```

This is what I see in the database:

```
SINGER_ID   SINGER_NAME
1           Ricky Martin
2           Madonna
3           Elvis Presley
4           Luciano Pavarotti
```

Now update a record using `merge()`

```
SessionFactory sef = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sef.openSession();
Singer singer = new Singer();
singer.setId(2);
singer.setName("Luciano Pavarotti");
session.merge(singer);
session.flush();
```

This is what I see in the database:

```
SINGER_ID   SINGER_NAME
1           Ricky Martin
2           Luciano Pavarotti
3           Elvis Presley
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161224/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-saving-methods-in-hibernate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge

Answer (score 159, accepted):

[JPA specification](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317) contains a very precise description of semantics of these operations, better than in javadoc:

> The semantics of the **persist**
>   operation, applied to an entity X are
>   as follows:
>
> - If X is a new entity, it
>     becomes managed. The entity X will be
>     entered into the database at or before
>     transaction commit or as a result of
>     the flush operation.
> - If X is a
>     preexisting managed entity, it is
>     ignored by the persist operation.
>     However, the persist operation is
>     cascaded to entities referenced by X,
>     if the relationships from X to these
>     other entities are annotated with the
>     `cascade=PERSIST` or `cascade=ALL`
>     annotation element value or specified
>     with the equivalent XML descriptor
>     element.
> - If X is a removed entity,
>     it becomes managed.
> - If X is a
>     detached object, the
>     `EntityExistsException` may be thrown
>     when the persist operation is invoked,
>     or the `EntityExistsException` or
>     another `PersistenceException` may be
>     thrown at flush or commit time.
> - For
>     all entities Y referenced by a
>     relationship from X, if the
>     relationship to Y has been annotated
>     with the cascade element value
>     `cascade=PERSIST` or `cascade=ALL`, the
>     persist operation is applied to Y.

---

> The semantics of the **merge** operation
>   applied to an entity X are as follows:
>
> - If X is a detached entity, the state
>     of X is copied onto a pre-existing
>     managed entity instance X' of the same
>     identity or a new managed copy X' of X
>     is created.
> - If X is a new entity
>     instance, a new managed entity
>     instance X' is created and the state
>     of X is copied into the new managed
>     entity instance X'.
> - If X is a
>     removed entity instance, an
>     `IllegalArgumentException` will be
>     thrown by the merge operation (or the
>     transaction commit will fail).
> - If X
>     is a managed entity, it is ignored by
>     the merge operation, however, the
>     merge operation is cascaded to
>     entities referenced by relationships
>     from X if these relationships have
>     been annotated with the cascade
>     element value `cascade=MERGE` or
>     `cascade=ALL` annotation.
> - For all
>     entities Y referenced by relationships
>     from X having the cascade element
>     value `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL`, Y
>     is merged recursively as Y'. For all
>     such Y referenced by X, X' is set to
>     reference Y'. (Note that if X is
>     managed then X is the same object as
>     X'.)
> - If X is an entity merged to X',
>     with a reference to another entity Y,
>     where `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL` is
>     not specified, then navigation of the
>     same association from X' yields a
>     reference to a managed object Y' with
>     the same persistent identity as Y.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I see the semantics of both definitions. But the question is about the differences between them. Perhaps present the list of states and 2 sub-sections for each different behavior of `persist` vs `merge`?

Comment: if entity is already managed i.e saved or retrieved from db and then changed but not detached. What should be used `persist` or `merge`

Comment: if we wanted to read pages of docs, we wouldn't be looking at a Stackoverflow answer... -1

Answer (score 36):

This is coming from `JPA`. In a very simple way:

- `persist(entity)` should be used with totally new entities, to add them to DB (if entity already exists in DB there will be EntityExistsException throw).
- `merge(entity)` should be used, to put entity back to persistence context if the entity was detached and was changed.

Comment: can you please add a source to your explanation? Thanks.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka such explaination, as I remember, I have found in a "Beginning Java EE 7" book.

Answer (score 21):

Persist should be called only on new entities, while `merge` is meant to reattach detached entities.

If you're using the assigned generator, using `merge` instead of `persist` can cause a redundant SQL statement.

Also, calling merge for managed entities is also a mistake since managed entities are automatically managed by Hibernate, and their state is synchronized with the database record by the dirty checking mechanism upon flushing the Persistence Context.

Comment: if entity is already managed i.e saved or retrieved from db and then changed but not detached. What should be used `persist` or `merge`

Comment: You shouldn't call any method if the entity is managed. Just let Hibernate do the UPDATE automatically.

Comment: tx. does it mean that at the time of commit or at the time of session getting closed, all managed entities will be saved in to DB automatically.

Comment: Yes, prior to commit, there's an auto-flush, unless you are using a read-only Session or Tx.

Comment: I understand above + `If you're using the assigned generator, using merge instead of persist can cause a redundant SQL statement`. Tx. But spring data jpa [save](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/spring-data-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L605) is using `merge` in all other cases except when entites are new ie. even when entities are managed. Why is this so?? Users may call save unknowingly on managed entities too only to trigger a merge(again unknowingly) and there is nothing stopping them

Comment: The Spring Data JpaRepository is broken, that's why. Better use the [HibernateRepository](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/blob/master/hibernate-types-55/src/main/java/com/vladmihalcea/spring/repository/HibernateRepository.java) instead, as it fixes that `save` issue.

Comment: thats very disappointing to know that spring guys would do it in a non-standard way.. and most of projects are using spring data api without realizing the pitfalls.. thanks pointing to HibernateRepo which does the job better.. but seems there's gonna be some learning curve.

Answer (score 2):

The most important difference is this:

- In case of the `persist` method, if the entity that is to be managed in the persistence context, already exists in the persistence context, the new one is ignored. (Basically, NOTHING happens)
- But in case of the `merge` method, the entity that is already managed in the persistence context will be replaced by the new entity (Simply, it gets updated) and a copy of this updated entity will then return back. (So from now on any changes should be made to this returned entity if you want to reflect your changes in the persistence context)