# Transitive Persistence & "detached entity passed to persist"

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, nhibernate-mapping

I think (hopefully) I'm doing all the right things. Googled it a lot, couldn't find what's wrong.

`Profile` can have multiple `Appointment`s.
Each `Appointment` has a `Department`.

- Departments are loaded and stored in a set, of course, detached.
- Appointments are created and get a Department from the set mentioned above.
- Appointments are added to Profile.
- Profile is made persistent.
- detached entity passed to persist is thrown for Department

Profile:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROFILE")
public class Profile {
/**
 * 
 */
private Set<Appointment> appointments = new HashSet<Appointment>();

/**
 * @return the appointments
 */

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE })
public Set<Appointment> getAppointments() {
    return appointments;
}

/**
 * @param appointments
 *            the appointments to set
 */
public void setAppointments(Set<Appointment> appointments) {
    this.appointments = appointments;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param apt
 */
public void addAppointment(Appointment apt) {
    apt.setProfile(this);
    appointments.add(apt);
}
}
```

Appointment:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPOINTMENT")
public class Appointment {
/**
 * 
 */
private Department department;
private Profile profile;


/**
 * @return the department
 */
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
@Index(name = "IDX_APPOINTMENT_DEPARTMENT")
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_APPOINTMENT_DEPARTMENT")
public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

/**
 * @param department
 *            the department to set
 */
public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}

/**
 * @return the profile
 */
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PROFILE_ID")
@Index(name = "IDX_APPOINTMENT_PROFILE")
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_APPOINTMENT_PROFILE")
public Profile getProfile() {
    return profile;
}

/**
 * @param profile
 *            the profile to set
 */
public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
    this.profile = profile;
}
}
```

Department:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class Department {
/**
 *
 */
private Set<Appointment> appointments = new HashSet<Appointment>();
private Set<Department> children = new HashSet<Department>();
private Department parent;


/**
 * @return the appointments
 */
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
public Set<Appointment> getAppointments() {
    return appointments;
}

/**
 * @param appointments
 *            the appointments to set
 */
public void setAppointments(Set<Appointment> appointments) {
    this.appointments = appointments;
}

/**
 * @return the children
 */
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE })
public Set<Department> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

/**
 * @param children
 *            the children to set
 */
public void setChildren(Set<Department> children) {
    this.children = children;
}

/**
 * @return the parent
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENTDEPARTMENT_ID")
@Index(name = "IDX_DEPARTMENT_CHILDREN")
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_DEPARTMENT_CHILDREN")
public Department getParent() {
    return parent;
}

/**
 * @param parent
 *            the parent to set
 */
public void setParent(Department parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
}
```

The errant `@Service` code:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
private Profile addNewProfile(ProfileJxb profileJxb) {
    logger.entry();

    Profile profile = new Profile(profileJxb);
    for (AppointmentJxb aptJxb : profileJxb.getAppointments()
            .getAppointmentJxb()) {
        Appointment apt = new Appointment(aptJxb);
        Department d = getDepartmentByName(aptJxb.getDepartment()); // previously fetched
        apt.setDepartment(d);
        // d.getAppointments().add(apt); // another failed attempt, this results in LazyInitException

        profile.addAppointment(apt);
    }

    profile = profileDao.makePersistent(profile); // Exception thrown here!

    logger.exit();
    return profile;
}
```

I hope I'm missing something, as I'm fetching and setting `Department` in a persistent state to avoid this exception.

Thank you.

Comment: Please check out this answer for a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/jpa-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist/13500921#13500921

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to save a new entity that references detached entities via cascaded relationships you have to use `merge()` instead of `persist()`, **but it's not the best way to solve this problem**.

The real problem is that `department` relaionship has cascading at all. Cascading makes sense when referring to entities that the entity in question logically own. But in your case you have a predefined set of `Department`s that is managed separately. Therefore you never need to cascade any operation from `Appointment` to `Department`.

So, the best solution is to remove cascading from `department` relationship.

Comment: @axtvat that was it, thank you. One question, How can I call merge when Profile is new, Appointment is new, only a Department is not?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509086/what-is-the-difference-between-persist-and-merge-in-hibernate. But I should emphasize the point that replacing `persist()` with `merge()` is not the best way to solve this problem, it would be better to configure cascading in logically correct way instead.