# SPRING DATA JPA save @OneToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I try to persist parent entity with one to many relation:

```
@Entity
public class TrainEx  {
    private Set<TrainCompositionEx> trainCompositionsByTrainId;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  mappedBy = "trainByTrainId")
    public Set<TrainCompositionEx> getTrainCompositionsByTrainId() {
        return trainCompositionsByTrainId;
    }

    public void setTrainCompositionsByTrainId(Set<TrainCompositionEx> trainCompositionsByTrainId) {
        this.trainCompositionsByTrainId = trainCompositionsByTrainId;
    }
...
}
```

and child entity:

```
@Entity
public class TrainCompositionEx{
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "trainId", referencedColumnName = "trainId", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private TrainEx trainByTrainId;
....

}
```

So I recieve my TrainEx trainEx from json POST endpoint:

```
 @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<Void> addTrain(@RequestBody TrainEx trainEx) throws Exception {
        trainService.add(trainEx);
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

json:

```
 {
    "trainId" : 5,
    "status" :  1,
    "maxWeight" :  200,
    "maxLength" :  35,
    "speed" :  60,
    "totalWeight" : 100,
    "totalLength" : 20,
    "trainCompositionsByTrainId": [{
        "wagonByWagonId": {"wagonId" : 2}
    }]
 }
```

after I save it like that:

```
...
@Transactional
    public TrainEx add(TrainEx trainEx) {

    for(TrainCompositionEx trainCompositionEx : trainEx.getTrainCompositionsByTrainId()){
        trainCompositionEx.setTrainByTrainId(trainEx);
        trainCompositionEx.setWagonByWagonId(
                em.getReference(WagonEx.class, trainCompositionEx.getWagonByWagonId().getWagonId()));
    }
    return trainExRepository.save(trainEx);
    }
    ...
```

But I received SQL *ERROR: null value in column "trainid" violates not-null constraint*, but as you see I setted *trainEx* entity to *TrainCompositionEx*, and I stopped in debug mode and trainId exists there:
[image]
so what should I do?

UPDATE1:
I investigated logs  and think that problem in that childs persist before parent entity, because I insert into *train_composition* table, but not into *train* table see:

```
Hibernate: insert into tms.public.train_composition (version, transportOrderId, wagonId, trainId) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: You are using trainCompositionEx.setTrainByTrainId(trainEx); and saving TrainEx, but creating and using TrainEx1 everywhere else.  This code doesn't make sense, as what is the new TrainEx1 for, and what does trainCompositionEx.setTrainByTrainId(trainEx) do?  Shouldn't the TrainCompositionEx get added to trainEx's trainCompositionsByTrainId  list instead of creating a new trainEx1 and new trainCompositionExes list?

Comment: sorry, my bad.. I wiil edit my post

Comment: updated, pls walk through my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `em.persist` for persisting classes. My parent entity has

```
@JsonProperty(TIMES)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Times> timesList = new HashSet<Times>();
```

while the child has

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Rider rider;
```

The code is

```
em.persist(rider);
for (Times t : rider.getTimes()) {
    t.setRider(rider);
}
```

for a new rider, for an existing rider I merge the new data into the old object.
The project is here: https://github.com/xtien/motogymkhana-server
The code is from `RiderDaoImpl` and `Rider` and `Times`.
This is what the project is for: http://www.gymcomp.com/eu

Comment: I cant persist rider first because I received full object with childs from json.
So if I do em.persist(parent) it already has childs inside

Comment: In my example, I persist a Rider, with multiple Times objects. None are preexisting. For a pre-existing Rider, my code doesn't do em.merge or anything. If you have a pre-existing child with a new parent, you should have a look at your datamodel. If you have a pre-existing parent with a new child, you can just add the child to the persisted parent.

Comment: I solved my problem using em.persist() instead of spring-data-jpa's SAVE() method.

Comment: Sorry, byt I thikk that spring data jpa SAVE() calls em.persist inside, but its seems somethinhg strange happend

Comment: Maybe you know, if i use em.merge instead of em.persists, why did it try  to save child entity first?

Comment: Don't use em.merge, unless you've read the documentation and you know exactly what merge does. Generally, you don't want to do a merge, just a persist, initially. After the persist, JPA handles persistence for you. This is a summary, it has a link to the JPA documentation:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509086/what-is-the-difference-between-persist-and-merge-in-hibernate