# Hibernate update one child in one to many

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate so I don't understand some basic things.
I have Entity A and B. And it's a one to many relationship. So A can have multiple B's.
Below is code to save when adding a new B to A. That's working.

```
    A a= this.aService.getAById(AID);
    b.setA(a);
    a.getBSet().add(b);
    this.aService.saveA(a);
```

But how can I edit one B entity? Do I first have to remove the B entity that I want to edit from the Set? 
Really sorry if it's an obvious question. But I already searched with Google and the only examples I can find is when you make new entities and not edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get B from the database.

```
B b = this.bService.getBById(BID);
...
//update b
this.bService.updateB(b);
```

Comment: So retrieve B that I want to edit. update B and that's it? Don't i have to edit the set that A which contains the B that I want to edit?

Comment: You might as well want to upvote and accept this answer so that it could be of help to others ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
//Whether you want update entity B:
Public void updateBEntity(Integer idB) {
 B b = session.get(B.class, idB);
//For edit you only have to use the set's methods:
b.setName(anything);
b.setPosition(2);
//final y, that's all
session.merge(b);
} 
//In your class controller or Action
```

More information about merge/persist:

[What is the difference between persist() and merge() in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509086/what-is-the-difference-between-persist-and-merge-in-hibernate)