# hibernate one to many mapping bidirectional merge

Tags: hibernate

I have two tables like below. Parent and child relation.

Parent table:

`parent_id` is primary key auto generated

Child table:

`parent_id`, `child_id` primary keys and `parent_id` is foreign key

When I am trying to insert new row in primary table, child table also its inserting (working fine). When I am trying to update parent table using merge operation, **in child table not able to insert new row** but able to update the existing rows and getting the below error.

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column `parent_id`, table
>   `Test.Sample.child`; column does not allow nulls.

INSERT fails.

Comment: Please add relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
 cascade=ALL
```

annotation according to your referencing mappings.

Check here for more details. [What is the difference between persist() and merge() in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509086/what-is-the-difference-between-persist-and-merge-in-hibernate)

Note: If you supply your mappings and sample usage scenario, your question can be answered more clearly.