# JPA update query without transaction - is transaction mandatory?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I'm trying to do insert via a native query with JPA, but I don't want to create a transaction:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO person (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES ('1','Ronnie','Dio')");
int count = query.executeUpdate();
```

this ends up with the TransactionRequiredException:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:99)
```

However, if I unwrap the Hibernate session and execute the same query - it works:

```
Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO person (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES ('1','Ronnie','Dio')");
int count = query.executeUpdate();
```

So my question is - what am I doing wrong in the first sample? Is transaction really required to execute insert/update/delete queries in JPA? 
If it is, is there any link to documentation that specifies it clearly? If it's not - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't avoid transaction creation. You only can make it implicit (like via session)

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are building an application that does not run inside a container supporting *JTA* managed transactions. In such an environment, you have to handle/manage transactions for yourself, i.e., you have to control when transactions are opened, committed or rolled back. This scenario is referred to as *resource-local entity manager*.

In section ***7.5.2** Resource-local EntityManagers* of the official [JPA 2.2 specification](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/javaee/jpa-spec/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) (p. 345) we find:

> An entity manager whose transactions are controlled by the application through the `EntityTransaction`
> API is a *resource-local entity manager*. A resource-local entity manager transaction is mapped
> to a resource transaction over the resource by the persistence provider. Resource-local entity managers
> may use server or local resources to connect to the database and are unaware of the presence of JTA
> transactions that may or may not be active

Further down in the spec document the `EntityTransaction` interface is given. It allows you to call

1. `begin()` to *"Start a resource transaction"*
2. `commit()` to *"Commit the current resource transaction, writing any
   unflushed changes to the database."*
3. `rollback()` to *"Roll back the current resource transaction."* in case something went wrong on the database side while committing changes.

That's for the theory part.
For your code example, you might want to change it as follows:

```
EntityTransaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = em.getTransaction();
    // start a new transaction, i.e. gather changes from here on...
    tx.begin();

    // do your changes here
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO person (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES ('1','Ronnie','Dio')");
    int count = query.executeUpdate();

    // write changes to database via commit
    tx.commit();
} catch(RuntimeException re) {
    if(tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
        // ensure no semi-correct changes are pending => cleanup
        tx.rollback();
    }
    // handle exception, log it somewhere...
}
```

This should avoid the `TransactionRequiredException` you encounter. Moreover, you should avoid the use `createNativeQuery`, as you are mis-using a fundamental concept of an Object-Relational-Mapper (ORM), i.e. the mapper will transform objects into tuples and vice versa for you. This - in general - should ease the pain of writing insert/update queries for a large amount of domain entities.

Have a look into section *3.1.1 EntityManager Interface* (p. 65) of the spec document linked above and make use of the methods

- `persist(..)` - *"Make an instance managed and persistent."* or
- `merge(..)` - *"Merge the state of the given entity into the current persistence context."*

For more infos on the difference of both approaches see the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1069992/2849346) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4509389/2849346).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a native query , I would recommend to create a JPA entity for the person and with JPARepository you can use a save method for the person to insert any record.