# Problem with persistence provider in a jpa and struts project

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, struts, jpa-2.2

I'm developing a java ee aplication using jpa to control a mysql db and struts.
Unfortunately when I run the project on a tomcat server I get this error.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named prova
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:56)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:34)
    test.testing.initEntityManager(testing.java:37)
    test.testing.add(testing.java:16)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:440)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:279)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.s2hibernatevalidator.interceptor.HibernateValidatorInterceptor.intercept(HibernateValidatorInterceptor.java:38)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
```

I've already searched online for a solution, but nothing fixed my problem.
Here are the files:

**src/test/Libro.java**

[image]

**src/test/testing.java**

[image]

**src/META-INF/persistence.xml**

[image]

**src/struts.xml**

[image]

**WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml**

[image]

**WebContent/index.xml**

[image]

Project

**View:**

[image]

**Lib:**

[image]

Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: Please post text as text, not as images of text.

Answer (score 1):

### Main issue

From the *screenshot* **Lib** we can see that you have a very "mixed" combination of libraries. Here lies the problem! You can not mix different API levels of the JPA. You mixed the very old/early release version 1.x with the most recent variant of [JPA 2.2](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf).

You put both `persistence-api-1.0.2.jar` and `javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar`  into the *lib* directory within the `WEB-INF` of the project. This causes conflicts at runtime.

Therefore:

- Remove the outdated `persistence-api-1.0.2.jar` from the folder and check if that solves the observed exception. If other exceptions occur, there are more inconsistencies at runtime with your setup.

### Other comments & changes

You mis-use the concept of transaction handling in the class `testing` within the method `createPlaces()`. Your code is:

```
em.persist();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

which puts the `persist()` call outside of the controlled Transaction you open after that line. Instead of persisting as above,  you should better reformulate these lines as below. The snippet moves the `persist` operation within the boundaries of a transaction:

```
EntityTransaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    // Only within a tx to prevent inconsistent states in the DB if sth fails here!
    em.persist(); 
    tx.commit();
} catch(RuntimeException) {
    if(if(tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
        tx.rollback();
    }   
}
```

For further details check another [answer on transaction handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50983893/2849346) I once wrote. It refers to JPA 2.2 and gives you further depth on this topic.

Hope it helps.