# Why would EntityManager.merge(entity) return a wrong object which is not the same with the old one?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here is what was going on:
[image: what was going on]

I had read the question before asking this question:
[What is the difference between persist() and merge() in JPA and Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509086/what-is-the-difference-between-persist-and-merge-in-jpa-and-hibernate)

But what I am wondering is the copy one (return by merge) should be the same with the old one, you can see it is not from the pic.

I am using:

- Spring data jpa:1.11.12
- hibernate:5.3.7.final

I am a newbie to hibernate, I guess it is a problom of hibernate's serialization and deserialization.Or is it the designed behavior?

Comment: Please read the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509086/what-is-the-difference-between-persist-and-merge-in-jpa-and-hibernate

Comment: Solved already.The reason for this is overriding hibernate UserType#deepCopy in a wrong way.