# JPA merge unable to update values in table

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to use JPA to make a simple update to my table column in MYSQL.

Here is the snippet:

```
public Node get_folder(long fileID) {
    try {
        List resList = nodeFacade.list_parent(fileID, LinkType.FILE);
        List resList1 = nodeFacade.list_parent(fileID, LinkType.VER_LINKS);
        if (resList == null) {
            throw new Exception("failed to get folder of a file." + 
                nodeFacade.getMsg());
        }
        if (resList.size() > 1) {
            throw new Exception("one file cannot be attached to more than one folder(s).");
        }

        //fixed bugs: modified here to display different version
        if(resList1.size()==1){
            Fmedia fmedia = em.find(fileID,Fmedia.class);
            fmedia.setFstatus(2);
            em.merge(fmedia);
            return (Node) resList1.get(0);
        }
```

Now, fmedia is the table and I want to update an existing record of a value in `fstatus` column of the table. The error I got was:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'FEXT' cannot be null

`FEXT` is a column in the same table and it's a not nullable column but there's already a value tied to that record.The exception is thrown at the line `em.merge(fmedia)`. I am confused what is the issue here.

I couldn't use `save` since my JPA is the older version.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Entity code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fmedia")
public class Fmedia implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NODEID")
    private Long nodeid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FONAME")
    private String foname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FGNAME")
    private String fgname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FEXT")
    private String fext;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FFULPATH")
    private String ffulpath;
    @Column(name = "FTYPE")
    private int ftype;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FSIZE")
    private long fsize;
    @Column(name = "FREMARK")
    private String fremark;
    @Column(name = "FSTATUS")
    private int fstatus;
    @Column(name = "FDESC")
    private String fdesc;
    @Column(name = "MODIFYDATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date ModifyDate;
    @Size(max = 3000)
    @Column(name = "FNTFREMARK")
    private String fntfremark;
    @Transient
    private Fverinfo fver;
```

Comment: `fileID` is your `@Id` in `FMedia` ? Show the entity code also.

Comment: Yea but it's passed as parameter to NodeID. Edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge does not do that you need to fetch the existing entity and update that entity instead of persisting a new one with same id, so like:

```
Fmedia fmedia = em.find(FMEdia.class, fileId);
fmedia.setFstatus(2);
em.persist(fmedia);
```

Merge is for attaching existing but detached entity to persistence context and your `new FMedia(..)` is not detached but just new.

Comment: But isn't persist like `insert`? It's gonna insert new records to the table?

Comment: @daredevil Not exactly. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4509086/6413377) for example.

Comment: I tried your way but I can't resolve the find method because my fileID is declared as `long`

Comment: So we use persist instead?

Comment: Does using fileID able to retrieve it in Fmedia class since it's NodeID in the fmedia class but i am passing fileID to it. I mean fmedia class doesn't have FileID but just nodeID but they are both the same.

Comment: you are passing a long/Long value of the entitys id field, the names of these fields does not matter in this case.

Comment: Well your answer does work. It does update the value to 2. However, it doesn't hide the button though

Answer (score 2):

Merge is used for detach entities. 
If you want to update an existing entity, use **fetch + update**.

1) fetch exiting Entity by nodeid

2) update necessary fields on that Entity (e.g. fmedia.setFstatus(2))

3) save the entity (if you're using Hibernate, the save is not necessary, Hibernate will still issue an Update statement)

```
Fmedia fmedia = repository.findOne(nodeid); //manged entity-update
fmedia.setFstatus(2); // hibernate will issue an update, cause the entity is managed
repository.save(fmedia) //redundant save anti-pattern, don't call save
```

Using entityManager:

```
entityManager.find(Fmedia.class, nodeId);
```

If you want to fetch your entity based on something else, rather than the primaryId, you will have to crate a query:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select m from Fmedia m where m.foname = :foname");
```

Comment: How would I fetch from Hibernate?

Comment: are you using entityManager or spring JPA repositories?

Comment: Entity Manager only

Comment: entityManager.find(Fmedia.class, nodeId);

Comment: I see, however nodeID should be replaced by fileID

Comment: Cool,but does fileID able to retrieve the NodeID since it's passing fileID argument but in find fmedia, it's doesn't have fileID

Comment: No, it won't work. Are you saying you try to load an entity from the DB where the criteria parameter is not present in the Entity? I believe this is starting to deviate from the original question.

Comment: I just tested your solution and it does work. Do you  mean find(nodeID) won't work or find(fileID) wont work?