# Hibernate ManyToMany works like OneToMany

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I' m tring to make an example to see table output of ManyToMany relationship managed by Hibernate. Everthing seems well. However, some rows are duplicated. I do not know why.
My Scenario is that I have 2 simple Classes Author & Book. Book can have more than one author and Author can have more than one book.

Let' s see classes and mysql table output.

Book.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book {

@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GEN_BOOK", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "TABLE_SEQ_GEN_BOOK", initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_GEN_BOOK")
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private long id;

@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String name;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Author.class)
private Set authors = new HashSet();

//setter/getters
```

Author.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Author")
public class Author {

@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GEN_AUTHOR", initialValue = 1, sequenceName = "TABLE_SEQ_GEN_AUTHOR", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_GEN_AUTHOR", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private long id;

@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "authors")
private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<Book>();

//setter/getters
```

main method is

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Author author1 = new Author();
    author1.setName("author1");
    Author author2 = new Author();
    author2.setName("author2");
    Author author3 = new Author();
    author3.setName("author3");

    Book book1 = new Book();
    book1.setName("book1");
    Book book2 = new Book();
    book2.setName("book2");
    Book book3 = new Book();
    book3.setName("book3");
    Book book4 = new Book();
    book4.setName("book4");

    book1.getAuthors().add(author1);
    book1.getAuthors().add(author2);

    book2.getAuthors().add(author1);
    book2.getAuthors().add(author2);
    book2.getAuthors().add(author3);

    book3.getAuthors().add(author2);
    book3.getAuthors().add(author3);

    book4.getAuthors().add(author3);
    DbOperations.getInstance().save(book1);
    DbOperations.getInstance().save(book2);
    DbOperations.getInstance().save(book3);
    DbOperations.getInstance().save(book4);

 }
```

Mysql Table output is below: (i can create the same overview without having transition table)

```
mysql> show tables;
+------------------------+
| Tables_in_hibernatedb1 |
+------------------------+
| author                 |
| book                   |
| book_author            |
| table_seq_gen_author   |
| table_seq_gen_book     |
+------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from book_author;
+----------+------------+
| books_ID | authors_ID |
+----------+------------+
|        1 |          1 |
|        1 |          2 |
|        2 |          3 |
|        2 |          4 |
|        2 |          5 |
|        3 |          6 |
|        3 |          7 |
|        4 |          8 |
+----------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from book;
+----+-------+
| ID | NAME  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | book1 |
|  2 | book2 |
|  3 | book3 |
|  4 | book4 |
+----+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from author;
+----+---------+
| ID | NAME    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | author1 |
|  2 | author2 |
|  3 | author1 |
|  4 | author2 |
|  5 | author3 |
|  6 | author2 |
|  7 | author3 |
|  8 | author3 |
+----+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My Expectation is to see tables like below:

```
mysql> select * from book_author;
+----------+------------+
| books_ID | authors_ID |
+----------+------------+
|        1 |          1 |
|        1 |          2 |
|        2 |          1 |
|        2 |          2 |
|        2 |          3 |
|        3 |          2 |
|        3 |          3 |
|        4 |          3 |
+----------+------------+


mysql> select * from book;
+----+-------+
| ID | NAME  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | book1 |
|  2 | book2 |
|  3 | book3 |
|  4 | book4 |
+----+-------+

mysql> select * from author;
+----+---------+
| ID | NAME    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | author1 |
|  2 | author2 |
|  3 | author3 |
+----+---------+


DBOperation.class

 public Object save(Object o) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    Object merge = null;
    try {
        merge = session.merge(o);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        transaction.rollback();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return merge;
}
```

Comment: what does `DbOperations.getInstance().save()` do? if it creates a new entity manager (i.e. Persistence context) on every call, so this means that every time it saves a fresh version of the entities, you can then even call `DbOperations.getInstance().save(book1);` multiple times and expect to see multiple entries of Book1 in the Book table

Comment: It creates a new session then calls merge method. Please see in above(i have added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You use bidirectional `@ManyToMany` [association](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional), so as hibernate documentation suggests, both sides of this association should be synchronized. It’s good practice to provide helper methods for adding or removing child entities.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book {

   @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GEN_BOOK", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "TABLE_SEQ_GEN_BOOK", initialValue = 1)
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_GEN_BOOK")
   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
   private String name;

   // do not use raw types
   // see for example this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321
   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

   public void addAuthor(Author author) {
      authors.add( author );
      author.getBooks().add( this );
   }

   public void removeAddress(Author author) {
      authors.remove( author );
      author.getBooks().remove( this );
   }
   
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
      // As you use Set collections for Author and Book
      // you should override equals/hashCode
      // and these implementation should be based on @NaturalIds
      // not on @Ids
   }
   
   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      // ...
   }
}
```

2. For new entities you should use `persist(entity)`, `merge(entity)` should be used, to put entity back to persistence context if the entity was detached and was changed.
   See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509086/what-is-the-difference-between-persist-and-merge-in-jpa-and-hibernate).

So, you should do something like this:

```java
Author author1 = new Author();
author1.setName("author1");
Author author2 = new Author();
author2.setName("author2");
Author author3 = new Author();
author3.setName("author3");

Book book1 = new Book();
book1.setName("book1");
Book book2 = new Book();
book2.setName("book2");
Book book3 = new Book();
book3.setName("book3");
Book book4 = new Book();
book4.setName("book4");

book1.addAuthor(author1);
book1.addAuthor(author2);

book2.addAuthor(author1);
book2.addAuthor(author2);
book2.addAuthor(author3);

book3.addAuthor(author2);
book3.addAuthor(author3);

book4.addAuthor(author3);

Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

session.persist(book1);
session.persist(book2);
session.persist(book3);
session.persist(book4);

transaction.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: If I call merge method instead of persist/save, result is not changed. Save&Persist solves the problem when they are called in the same session. Thank you @SternK

Answer (score 0):

I was creating different sessions for each save method call and i was calling `session.merge()`. I have changed `DbOperations.getInstance().save(..)` method content to insert all given rows in the same session by calling `session.save()` instead of `session.merge()`. See updated method below and it works well now.

```
public void save(Object... obj) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            for (Object o: obj) {
                session.save(o);
            }
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```