# transform a simple query into hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, subquery, hql

I want to transform a simple query into hibernate

```
INSERT INTO TRXENTRIES (AMOUNT, BALANCE) 
VALUES (2500, (SELECT CURRENTBALANCE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMERID=1)+2500))
```

What is alternative solution in hibernate using save()?

Update Me !

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html#d0e2116 see this link this will help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745041/inserting-data-in-one-table-using-hql-in-hibernate see this answer as well

Comment: @ankit is it possible with `session.save(entity)` because this is ok for one table and but In my case there are one to many relation with table so save() return the ID (Generated Value) but query does not !

Comment: @ankit I have required only one value form other table ! your example take all value from other table ! :(

Answer (score 0):

you must:

1. Create an entity to map your INSERT table (i.e. TrxEntry)
2. Write an HQL query to fill your object
3. Save entity using session.merge()

Alternatively, you can use method createSqlQuery of session object to execute your SQL query and complete them with session.executeUpdate().

Sample:

Entity TrxEntry:

```
public class TrxEntry {
    private Double amount;
    private Double balance;

    -- add your get / set properties

    public Trxentry (Double amount, Double balance) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

Hql:

```
String hql = "select new TrxEntry(o.amount, o.balance)
from otherEntry o";
```

if you want calculate your o.balance as another subquery you can do without problem

The result of your query goes in

```
Query q = session.createQuery(hql);
session.merge(q);
```

Merge provides to save your entity

Comment: `In HQL, only the INSERT INTO … SELECT … is supported; there is no INSERT INTO … VALUES. HQL only support insert from another table.` so sql query concept will not apply in my case, I just require only one value from other table !

Comment: I will appreciate if your provide me the example with respect to `session.merge()` or `session.save()` :)

Comment: Hi, show here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170962/nhibernate-difference-between-session-merge-and-session-saveorupdate and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475363/differences-among-save-update-saveorupdate-merge-method-in-session-object

Comment: Dear difference I know! I required to save entity, and this entity contain one value from another table !

Comment: @Shahid Ghafoor: Dear the solution is in point 1. As you write your entity. BALANCE is a scalar property, so if you write your HQL query you fill that property with istantiate your constructor