# Hibernate merge

Tags: java, hibernate

I am testing hibernate and giving this query to

```
transaction = session.beginTransaction();
city = new City("A");
city  = (City)session.merge(city);
city.setName("B");
transaction.commit();
```

And I am getting those queries in the command line:

```
Hibernate: insert into CITY (name) values (?)
Hibernate: update CITY set name=? where CITY_ID=?
```

I am using merge not save, so why  hibernate is updating my object, It should not update. am it right? What is the mistake?

Comment: This link may be useful :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161224/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-saving-methods-in-hibernate

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I will try to explain using a more concrete example. Suppose you have a scenario like below :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
User userA = (User)session.get(User.class, 1101);
transaction.commit();
session.close();
// Since session is closed, userA is detached.

session = sessionFactory.openSession();
transaction = session.beginTransaction();
User userB = (User)session.get(User.class, 1101);
//Now here,  userB represents the same persistent row as userA.
//When an attempt to reattach userA occurs, an exception is thrown
session.update(userA);
transaction.commit();
session.close();
```

Exception when an attempt to reattach a Detached object, userA is made.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a   
different object with the same identifier value was already associated
with the session:

This is because Hibernate is enforcing that only a single instance of a Persistent    object exists in memory.
```

To get around the above problem, merge() is used, as shown below :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
User userA = (User)session.get(User.class, 1101);
transaction.commit();
session.close();
//userA is now detached as session is closed.

session = sessionFactory.openSession();
transaction = session.beginTransaction();
User userB = (User)session.get(User.class, 1101);
User userC = (User)session.merge(userA);
if (userB == userC) {
  System.out.println("Reattched user is equal");
}
transaction.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: Each `'conversation' (client request)` can have its own `userA` reference, yes?

Answer (score 4):

It's a sequencing issue. Actually not an issue. Hibernate is doing exactly what you told it to do. As @TejasArjun says, merge is about merging in deteched data. here's what is going on:

```
...
city  = (City)session.merge(city); 
// No different to save(). Hibernate schedules an insert to the
// database to store the current record.

city.setName("B"); 
// The object is now flagged as dirty and needing to be saved. 
// Hiberate automatically tracks properties on objects and knows when they change.

transaction.commit(); 
// Hibernate sees that 'city' has been changed since it was saved, 
// so it schedules an update to store the new data.
```

Comment: I got your point thanks for answer but even i can reach the above by this way:    
city.setName("q");
  
  
  session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  transaction = session.beginTransaction();
  
  session.update(city);
  
  transaction.commit();
Why then need merge() method? It is the same

Comment: See my example on usage of merge in second answer

Answer (score 0):

Because session is not closed yet and in persistence terms `city` object is still attached to session. So, any changes in that object will be listened by hibernate session and appropriate dml statement will be invoked.

Comment: that is right if i use save() not merge(). If it is still right for merge then what is the difference between save and merge?

Comment: Merge is useful when you have detached instances. In the above case, when you close the session you still have `city` object. Suppose, you make some changes to `city` object after closing the session. Now again you open a session and you want to make sure the changes are persisted. In this case you would use `merge` the city object with the session and hibernate will make sure the changes are reflected in database. `save` is primarily used to persist an entity and would give back the identifier.

Comment: in this case which u described even i can use update() to update it. no need to use merge() :(