# Hibernate+GWTP: session across multiple requests

Tags: hibernate, session, wizard, gwtp

I am trying to create a wizard-like registration where I have multiple pages with each one a form and a "save and continue" button.
I want to save the data of each form in a hibernate session and save it on the DB only at the end of the registration when the user confirms.
I am not an Hibernate expert but I understood that I need to create a "long session". How do I do that? Do I do that by leaving the transaction open? How do I retrieve the "dirty" entity from one request to the other ?
Say we have an GWTP action handler that does something like this

```
//page1 action           
public myAction1Result execute(myAction1Action action,ExecutionContext context) throws ActionException {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();

    User entityUser = new User();
    entityUser.setName(action.getName());
    session.save(entityUser); 

    return new myAction1Result();
}
```

Until the transaction will be open the userEntity won't be saved in the DB and will be transient. How I can retrieve it in another actionHandler?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible scenarios:

1.
Your ActionHandler should be a (session) singleton - therefore you don't need a hibernate transaction. You can simply edit and hold the object in your ActionHandler instance. After the workflow is finished you can call a seperated action (e.g. RegisterUserWorkflowCommitAction) which injects the main ActionHandler and commits your  edited object.

2.
Use [transaction.merge(user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846017/hibernate-merge).

```
//...
@Singleton
public class RegisterUserWorkflowActionHandler //...
//...
transaction = session.beginTransaction();
session.merge(action.getUser());
transaction.commit();
//...
```

3.
Hold the transaction using an field from your (singleton) ActionHandler.

```
//...
@Singleton
public class RegisterUserWorkflowActionHandler //...
//...
if(this.getOpenTransaction() == null) {
    this.setOpenTransaction(session.beginTransaction())
}
//...
```

4.
May have a look at [Errai JPA](http://docs.jboss.org/errai/2.2.0.Final/errai/reference/html_single/#sid-54493688). Maybe it's a great alternative for you.