# When to use merge() before save()?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm

I am just curious when to use `merge()` method before saving an object in hibernate.
I saw an example that uses `merge()` before saving with an object that has a many to many relationship with another object.

**Example** for using merge: `Role` has `ManyToMany` with `Permission` and it sets `List` of `Permission` in the `Role` object before saving.

So is that's only that case, when the saved object has relation with other objects?

I need good explanation and use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernte merge method will force Hibernate to copy any changes from other detached instances onto the instance you want to save, and thus merges all the changes in memory before the save.

Please refer to these posts below with details on the differences and examples..

[Different methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161224/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-saving-methods-in-hibernate)

[This has more detailed explanation with an example](http://www.stevideter.com/2008/12/07/saveorupdate-versus-merge-in-hibernate/)

Hope this helps.