# hibernate session.save() inserts different values than are at object

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have little problem. When I try insert new value to database, function save() inserts me different values ​​than are at object :(. What should I do?

Here is my function

```
public void updateListOfElements(List<Dokumenty> list) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            for (Dokumenty dokument : list) {
                Dokumenty dokumentToUpdate =
                        (Dokumenty) session.get(Dokumenty.class, dokument.getId());

                dokumentToUpdate.setAktywny('N');
                session.update(dokumentToUpdate);    

                // id z dupy wpisuje
                dokument.setId(10114);
                session.save(dokument);
            }

            transaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that it updating the same record or its inserting a different record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `saveOrUpdate` not `save`

```
 dokument.setId(10114);
 session.saveOrUpdate(dokument);
```

When you call `saveOrUpdate()` If the identifier exists, it will call update method else the save method will be called.

If you call `save()` method stores an object into the database. That means it insert an entry.

Before proceed have a look :[What are the differences between the different saving methods in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161224/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-saving-methods-in-hibernate)

**My suggetion:**`Always use saveOrUpdate //if record exists update otherwise new`

Answer (score 0):

Use `session.merge()`. Becuase, NonUniqueObjectException may be thrown when using Session.saveOrUpdate() in Hibernate - See more at: http://www.stevideter.com/2008/12/07/saveorupdate-versus-merge-in-hibernate/#sthash.WJEbdSaG.dpuf