# What is the identifier of a hibernate object

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am going through various hibernate methods like

```
persist()
save()
update()
merge()
```

All talk about differences in one returning identifier other returning not.

Can anyone tell me what is an identifier they are talking about?

What is the use of that?

I am sure it's not the Primary Key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between the different saving methods in Hibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161224/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-saving-methods-in-hibernate)

Comment: No it's a completely different question; I am asking what is an identifier not the differences between hibernate methods.

Comment: Have you read the documentation?  You do not provide any references to "All talk about differences..."  Please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifier refers to the attribute *name* of `<id>` element in `.hbm` file or `@Id` annotation.

Mark the identifier property with `@Id`.

```
@Entity
public class Person {
   @Id Integer getId() { ... }
   ...
}
```

In `hbm.xml`, use the `<id>` element which defines the mapping from that property to the primary key column.

```
<id
    name="propertyName"                                
    type="typename"                                    
    column="column_name"                               
    unsaved-value="null|any|none|undefined|id_value"   
    access="field|property|ClassName">                 
    node="element-name|@attribute-name|element/@attribute|."

    <generator class="generatorClass"/>
</id>
```

- name (optional): the name of the *identifier* property.
- type (optional): a name that indicates the Hibernate type.
- column (optional - defaults to the property name): the name of the primary key column.
- unsaved-value (optional - defaults to a "sensible" value): an identifier property value that indicates an instance is newly instantiated (unsaved), distinguishing it from detached instances that were saved or loaded in a previous session.
- access (optional - defaults to property): the strategy Hibernate should use for accessing the property value.

### Related link

- [Hibernate docs mapping-declaration-id](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-id)