# Difference between save and saveAndFlush in Spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to learn spring data JPA by testing some CRUD operation via `JpaRepository`.

I came across two methods `save` and `saveAndFlush`.
I don't get the difference between these two. On calling `save` also my changes are getting saved into database so what is the use of `saveAndFlush`.

Answer (score 184):

On `saveAndFlush`, changes will be flushed to DB immediately in this command. With `save`, this is not necessarily true, and might stay just in memory, until `flush` or `commit` commands are issued.

But be aware, that even if you flush the changes in transaction and do not commit them, the changes still **won't** be visible to the outside transactions until the commit in this transaction.

In your case, you probably use some sort of transactions mechanism, which issues `commit` command for you if everything works out fine.

Comment: _"won't be visible to the outside transactions until the commit in this transaction"_  It depends on the isolation level of the other transactions. If a transaction's isolation level is READ_UNCOMMITTED，then it will see what has been flushed but not yet committed by other transactions.

Comment: but, in my project, I use save(), saveAll() & it persists in DB without commit or flush calling explicitly. Then why should I prefer saveAndFlush? FLush mode all those things are in default mode

Comment: P Satish Patro, saveAndFlush() is used for immediate flush. If you use save(), the flush action will be handled by JPA later.

Answer (score 54):

Depending on the hibernate flush mode that you are using (`AUTO` is the default) `save` may or may not write your changes to the DB straight away. When you call `saveAndFlush` you are enforcing the synchronization of your model state with the DB.

If you use flush mode AUTO and you are using your application to first save and then select the data again, you will not see a difference in bahvior between `save()` and `saveAndFlush()` because the select triggers a flush first. See the [documention](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#objectstate-flushing).

Comment: sorry but if I `save` an entity and again the same one, you mean with `save` the second command won't throw an exception for duplication for example??

Comment: @Bludream Yes, it is my understanding that calls to `save` are idempotent. See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161224/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-saving-methods-in-hibernate) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

Both methods are used to save entities to the database. Flushing is the process of synchronizing the state of the persistence context with the underlying database.

When using **saveAndFlush** method, data immediately flush to the database and to do it with the **save** method we need to call **flush**() method explicitly.
Using flush can read saved changes at a later step during the same transaction but before the commit. So still can **rollback** if no need to **commit**.

Answer (score 2):

The "save" method is used to save an entity to the database. When you call the "save" method, the entity is first persisted to the database's transactional buffer, and then, when the transaction is committed, the entity is saved to the database. The "save" method returns the saved entity.

The "save and flush" method, on the other hand, does the same thing as "save", but additionally forces the database to immediately write the pending changes to disk. This can be useful in cases where you need to ensure that the data is immediately persisted to the database, rather than waiting for the transaction to commit.

In summary, the main difference between "save" and "save and flush" in Spring Data is that the latter immediately writes the pending changes to the database, while the former waits until the transaction is committed to do so.

If you want to save a new entity and use its ID within the same transaction, you should use the "save" method followed by a call to the "flush" method.

When you call the "save" method, the entity is persisted to the transactional buffer, and a temporary ID is assigned to the entity. This ID is generated by the underlying persistence framework and is not the final ID that will be assigned to the entity when it is saved to the database.

By calling the "flush" method, you force the underlying persistence framework to immediately write the pending changes to the database. This causes the temporary ID assigned to the entity to be replaced with the final ID assigned by the database.

Once the "flush" method has been called, you can safely use the ID of the newly saved entity within the same transaction.