# Unable to persist object in database using Spring data jpa Repositories and JtaTransactionManager

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jta

trying to find what went wrong with my code which worked fine until i moved to JTAtransactionManager it is having issue saving the record in database but fetching the record working fine, below is my sample TransactionConfig class and service class method.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionConfig {


    @Bean(name = "userTransaction")
    public UserTransaction userTransaction() throws Throwable {
        UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp = new UserTransactionImp();
        //userTransactionImp.setTransactionTimeout(10000);
        return userTransactionImp;
    }

    @Bean(name = "atomikosTransactionManager", initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    public TransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager() throws Throwable {
        UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
        userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(false);

        return userTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @DependsOn({ "userTransaction", "atomikosTransactionManager" })
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Throwable {
        UserTransaction userTransaction = userTransaction();

        TransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager = atomikosTransactionManager();
        return new JtaTransactionManager(userTransaction, atomikosTransactionManager);
    }

}


---Employee Service Class Method---

@Transactional
public void appExample() {

    try {

        Employee emp = new Employee();

        emp.setFirstName("Veer");
        emp.setLastName("kumar");

        empRepo.save(emp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: where is the declaration and definition of empRepo? can you please include that as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is with `empRepo.save()` method call. This call is not committing any changes to database as you are using @Transactional for transaction management.

Please try with `empRepo.saveAndFlush()` which will immediately flush the data into database. You can refer answer [Difference between save and saveAndFlush in Spring data jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203875/difference-between-save-and-saveandflush-in-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: thanks for reply, i tried with saveAndFlush but still no luck.

Comment: @veeru can you try removing Transactional annotation from addExample method. I think this is causing issue.