# Hibernate - multiples delete + insert operations without calling flush method causes duplicates

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a relationship:

```
Parent {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child> children= new ArrayList<>();
}

Child {
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;
}
```

I want to remove all children and add new ones. That's why I call:

```
List<Child> newChildren = Arrays.asList(firstChild, secondChild);
parent.getChildren().clear();
parent.getChildren().addAll(newChildren);
parentRepository.save(parent); - I'm using spring data
```

However I saw that when I call the above code twice (I have more complicated logic, but this is the simplest case how I was able to reproduce my problem) without calling `flush()` method, Hibernate adds duplicate entries to the database (parent will have 4 children):

```
parent.getChildren().clear();
parent.getChildren().addAll(newChildren);
parentRepository.save(parent);
parent.getChildren().clear();
parent.getChildren().addAll(newChildren);
parentRepository.save(parent);
```

Replacing `save`with `saveAndFlush` fixes above code and causes that parent has only 2 children.

Why is it necessary to call flush method before deleting and inserting new children to the parent?

Comment: Maybe this can give you an hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203875/difference-between-save-and-saveandflush-in-spring-data-jpa#21204085

Answer (score 0):

From `CrudRepository#save` [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-):

> S save(S entity)
>
> Saves a given entity. **Use the returned instance for further operations** as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely.

So I believe your problem will be solved when you replace by:

```
parent = parentRepository.save(parent);
```

In your code, you continue operation on entity not attached to context, thus causing duplications.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't fix this issue.