# spring data jpa saveandflush method

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I do understand the difference between the method save and the method saveAndFlush of the class JpaRepository Spring Data JPA. As per my understanding, the save method will run and commit the sql only at the end of the transaction whereas the saveAndFlush method will synchronize the persistence context with the database by running the SQL statement but without committing it. Below is a sample code where I Wanted to experience with it and please review it.

This is the repository class for the update

```
@Repository
public interface ClassRepository extends JpaRepository<ClassA, Long> {

    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query(value = "UPDATE class e SET e.class_name = ? WHERE e.employee_id = ?", nativeQuery = true)
    int updateClassNative(String className, String empId);

}
```

This is the test case where I am testing the methods

```
    @Test
    void saveAndUpdateWithFlushJPA() {
        ClassA classA = ClassA.builder().className("Test").employeeId("S0810").build();

    this.classRepository.save(classA);
    int size = this.classRepository.updateClassNative("TestQ", "S0810");
    assertThat(size).isEqualTo(1);
}
```

In the above test case, the test passed. I was not expecting the record to be saved since I am using the save method. In the source code, the save method is wrapped with @Transactional. Is it because of that the save method is already committing the insert statement?

Ashley

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between save and saveAndFlush in Spring data jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203875/difference-between-save-and-saveandflush-in-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: the save method might stay just in memory? That is your point.

Comment: @silentsudo Please read the question carefully.

Comment: @silentsudo I apologize for that but I have only edited the first line of my question. Just a few words.

Comment: I don't think I follow. How is using a native update query related to `save/saveAll` methods? Your code doesn't call either

Comment: @crizzis what should be the scenario then in order to compare save and saveAndFlush?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I see what you mean now. I'll post an answer in a minute

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your test scenario is that JPA always flushes the persistence context before executing a native query (this is also the default behaviour for JPQL queries, though it can be overriden). The rationale is that a query should report a state reflecting the changes already made in the current unit of work.

To see the difference between `save/saveAndFlush`, you can use the following test cases instead:

```
@Repository
public interface ClassRepository extends JpaRepository<ClassA, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM ClassA c")
    @QueryHints({
        @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.FLUSH_MODE, value = "COMMIT")
    })
    int countClassAEntities();
}

@Test
@Transactional
void saveAndUpdate() {
    int initialCount = classRepository.countClassAEntities(); 
    ClassA classA = ClassA.builder().className("Test").employeeId("S0810").build();
    classRepository.save(classA);
    int finalCount = classRepository.countClassAEntities();
    assertEquals(initialCount, finalCount);
}

@Test
@Transactional
void saveAndUpdateWithFlush() {
    int initialCount = classRepository.countClassAEntities(); 
    ClassA classA = ClassA.builder().className("Test").employeeId("S0810").build();
    classRepository.saveAndFlush(classA);
    int finalCount = classRepository.countClassAEntities();
    assertEquals(initialCount + 1, finalCount);
}
```

In the above setup, the count query has flush mode set to `COMMIT`, meaning that executing the query will not trigger a flush. If you were to use the default `repository.count()` method instead, the first test case would fail because by default, the flush mode is set to `AUTO`.

Comment: is there any need `@Transactional` with `saveAndFlush`?

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh Well, I added it for illustrative purposes, for both tests to have the same initial conditions. Without the tests being transactional, each repository method call creates its own transaction, so there would be no difference between `save` and `saveAndFlush`

Comment: @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.FLUSH_MODE, value = "COMMIT") This line is giving compilation error. Not applicable to methods.

Comment: Hi. I tried what you said it did not work. Your idea was really helpful. What worked for me is setting spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode to COMMIT in application.properties file. Thanks a lot for your help.