# Spring JPA Multithreading delete contention

Tags: java, postgresql, multithreading, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring JPA multi threaded program in which multiple threads are saving to one of the tables. I wanted to know what will happen in the following scenario:

2 threads pick up same object to process and `save` to the table. Data is successfully saved.
A contention resolution mechanism identifies that one of the data is a duplicate and makes a `delete` request. Will this delete also remove the object from the context of the first thread ?

(We have an intermittent issue appearing when an object which is supposed to be a successful return via the `save` method of JPA is suddenly logged as `null`.)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this you can try to use `saveAndFlush` instead of `save`. This might solve your problem of unexpected deletion.

Refer: [Difference between save and saveAndFlush in Spring data jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203875/difference-between-save-and-saveandflush-in-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: Tried this and it did not help.